# Error while creating procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure-definition

This is my procedure:

```
     DELIMITER $$
     CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test_final6() 
     BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `chef_ratings`(`chef_id`,`avg_total_no_votes`,`avg_total_rating`,`no_of_votes`,`avg_rating`)
    SELECT `chef_id`,(SELECT count(chef_id) FROM rates)/( SELECT count(DISTINCT chef_id) FROM rates),
    (( SELECT sum((`question_1` + `question_2` +`question_3` )/3) FROM rates ) / ( SELECT count(chef_id) FROM rates)),
    ( SELECT count(chef_id) FROM rates ),avg((`question_1`+`question_2`+`question_3`)/3)
    FROM rates GROUP BY `chef_id`;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting error :

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE sp_test_final6()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `chef_ratings`( `chef_id`, `avg_t' at line 1
```

Any idea why it is failing?

**Edited:** It works fine in mysql version 5.5 but in Server version: 4.1.22 it is giving this problem.  How we can fix without upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Stored procedure supported in MYSQL since 5.0 .Older version doesn't support stored procedure .

reference [link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569)